# sklearn model_selection Error: ImportError: cannot import name '_approximate_mode'

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to import sklearn model_selection but I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-6bc6f0a77ca9> in <module>()
----> 1 import sklearn.model_selection

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from ._split import BaseCrossValidator
      2 from ._split import KFold
      3 from ._split import GroupKFold
      4 from ._split import StratifiedKFold
      5 from ._split import TimeSeriesSplit

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 from ..utils import indexable, check_random_state, safe_indexing
---> 23 from ..utils import _approximate_mode
     24 from ..utils.validation import _num_samples, column_or_1d
     25 from ..utils.validation import check_array

ImportError: cannot import name '_approximate_mode'
```

I tried uninstalling scikit-learn and reinstalling it but I get the same error. My current version of scikit-learn is 0.21.2.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: pls provide the full code of your import process thx!

Answer (score 7):

I shutdown the kernel and restarted it again. Now it's working fine! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using python notebook. I found that error once when I have installed the package before importing. I have tested this at **Google AI notebook** and worked well.

**Save the notebook** -> shutdown the kernel -> close and open the notebook again.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the kernel or use the `importlib` library

```
from importlib import reload
sklearn= reload(sklearn)
```